# Lua: "dragging" sequence of elements within array

Tags: arrays, lua, element, lua-table

I'm trying to create a function that 'drags' a sequential number of elements to a new location within the array, constrained to the current size of the array. Other items should jiggle round the 'dragged' items.

For example, if my array has 7 elements and I want to drag the middle three...

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7  <-- keys
a, b, C, D, E, f, g  <-- values
```

The uppercase chars are the ones I want to 'drag'. If I drag to start of the array (drag to 1) the array would look like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7  <-- keys
C, D, E, a, b, f, g  <-- values
```

If I drag to position 5 (or above - can't be dragged outside current array size) the array would look like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7  <-- keys
a, b, f, g, C, D, E  <-- values
```

Any idea how I can achieve that using Lua in a non-crufty manner?

Comment: How big are the tables involved? How large are the dragged chains? I can think of two main ways to do this offhand but they scale differently to larger sized tables.

Comment: small tables and chains for the stuff i want to do, but if others use the code then potentially big tables with big chains.

Comment: Don't have time to write out an answer at the moment but one of the ideas is basically just get your start index and count `table.unpack(t, 1, start)` + `table.unpack(t, start + count)` + `table.unpack(t, start, start+count)` (with whatever `+`/`-` 1 is necessary on those to make it work. Though that requires looping to work. The other is repeated `table.remove`/`table.insert` pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using [`table.move`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move) available in Lua 5.3.

It copies the group to be dragged into another table and shifts values up or down to make room for the group.

```
 function drag(t, src, len, dest)
    local copy = table.move(t, src, src + len - 1, 1, {})

    if src >= dest then
        table.move(t, dest, src - 1, dest + len)
    else 
        table.move(t, src + len, dest + len - 1, src)
    end

    table.move(copy, 1, len, dest, t)
 end
```

Comment: That works very nicely! Despite the somewhat sparse official documentation, I'm starting to realise `table.move()` is a very flexible and useful function, especially considering its internal optimisations.

Answer (score 1):

```
function drag(t, src, len, dest)
  if len == 0 then return end
  local left, ctr, start, index, elem = math.min(src, dest), 0, 0
  local rot, size = dest - src, src + dest + len - 2 * left
  repeat
    start, index, elem = start + 1, start, t[left + start]
    repeat
      index = (index + rot) % size
      ctr, t[left + index], elem = ctr + 1, elem, t[left + index]
    until index < start
  until ctr == size
end

for K = 1, 5 do
  local tbl = {'a', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'f', 'g'}
  drag(tbl, 3, 3, K)
  print(table.concat(tbl))
end
```

Comment: Almost ;) It breaks if src + len > dest, eg:

__for K = 1, 7 do
  local tbl = {'a', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'f', 'g'}
  drag(tbl, 3, 3, K)
  print(table.concat(tbl))
end__

Comment: @Aubergine18 - You are trying to drag selected elements beyond the array ;)  An assertion `assert(math.max(src, dest) + len - 1 <= #t)` should be added if you wish to check this condition.