# What would be the most efficient way to shift objects in a Lua table based on choosing a slot?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table of objects, and a user can choose an object in the table at any given order in the table and place it in another slot in the table.  When that happens I need the table to shift from the selected dropped slot and fill the empty slot.  Not a swap, that's easy, but a shift at the point of placement.

so if I have this as a highly simplified example of my table

```
t = {a, b, c, d, e, f}
```

and the user chooses, say `e`, and wants to drop it into slot `b`.  how best would I

1. have `e` take the `b` slot
2. have all the values from "`b` to `d` shift right and then also fill
   the empty `e` slot?
3. how would I handle this shift no matter what one is chosen and where
   its moved in the table efficiently no matter what size the table
   might be?

Comment: `function move(t,old,new) local e=t[old]; for k=new,old,old>new and 1 or -1 do t[k],e=e,t[k] end end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move the item at position `old` to position `new` as you describe, you can use this:

```
table.insert(t, new, table.remove(t,old))
```

Here is your example:

```
t = {10,20,30,40,50,60}
print(table.concat(t, ','))
old = 5
new = 2
table.insert(t, new, table.remove(t,old))
print(table.concat(t, ','))
```

As for efficiency, the code above does shift some elements twice when they could have stayed where they were, but this will probably not matter unless the table is huge.

In Lua 5.3, you can probably do something better with `table.move`.

Comment: I'm using Corona SDK for a rummy style game and I'm going to use this to let the player sort cards in his hand manually.  and I believe they are using LUA 5.1. I was reading the lua docs and maybe I just didnt wrap my hand around the fact that it was this easy.  Thanks for the heads up, I tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation of shift using [`table.move`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move) which is efficient and available in Lua 5.3 as @lhf mentioned:

```
function shift(t, old, new)
    local value = t[old]
    if new < old then
       table.move(t, new, old - 1, new + 1)
    else    
       table.move(t, old + 1, new, old) 
    end
    t[new] = value
end
```

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation... does table.move reorder elements around the moved chain? If so it would certainly help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130855/lua-dragging-sequence-of-elements-within-array

Comment: it doesn't reorder anything, just copies multiple values to a new location. For your problem you could use move to shift values and create a copy of the moving segment.